# Error in mapping FormData structure Angular

Tags: angular, http, multipartform-data

I am trying to convert AJAX jQuery call with Angular HTTP POST request.

This is snippet of ajax jQuery

```js
$.ajax({
   url: env.URL,
   data: request,
   method: 'POST',
   timeout: 6000,
   success: function (response) {
     // business logic
   }
});
```

This is the structure of request headers and body:

[image]

**Response received back is an HTML form**.

Converting this to Angular:

```js
const header = new HttpHeaders();
header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
header.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
header.append('Accept', 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*');
const httpOptions = {
   responseType: 'text' as 'json', // if not converted, I get json parse error as return response is HTML e.g. error parsing `<` at line 28
   headers: header
};
const temp = new FormData();
Object.keys(request).forEach(key => temp.append(key, request[key]));

return this.http.post(env.URL, temp, httpOptions);
```

This is the structure of request headers and body:

[image]

In header, I have additional string getting inferred as `boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryGEf4TefkXkO6MbyV` also in form-data

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryGEf4TefkXkO6MbyV
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="address"

test test test
```

I have tried multiple permutation and combinations with header values and responseType like:

- not sending headers at all and let it get inferred by default as per standards
- Set content-type to `undefined`, `null`, `multipart/formdata`
- set responseType just to `text` (gives error), omitting responseType (gives error again) i.e. `Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"json"'.` as returned response is HTML.

Can you please help me fix structure of form data & content-type header sent in request!

Comment: Do you have any interceptor that may have modified the boundary?

Comment: @PaulEvans - No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find concrete solution for this, so a quick fix that resolved this issue was to:

- change POST request call to a GET request
- convert (form-data) payload to query params in URL:

```js
const header = new HttpHeaders();
header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

let queryParams = new HttpParams();
Object.keys(request).forEach(key => {
   queryParams = queryParams.append(key, request[key]);
});

const httpOptions = {
  responseType: 'text' as 'json',
  headers: header,
  params: queryParams
};

return this.http.get(env.URL, httpOptions);
```